# A single word for 'something that always works'?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a single word to express about a solution or a particular thing which always works/gives fruitful results/solves the problem?

Comment: One possibility is **infallible**.

Comment: Can you give us a context and an example sentence of how the potential word may be used? Also, what research have your done? fool-proof? dependable? reliable?

Comment: [Reliable](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/reliable)

Comment: ***dependable***

Comment: "does the trick" is used informally.

Comment: Mac operating system?

Comment: In British English, and after the tag line of a series of adverts for wood treatment products, something that 'does what it says in the tin'.

Comment: **panacea** is interesting in this context--often it's "no panacea"

Comment: How about *foolproof*?

Comment: *Failsafe* is another possibility.

Answer (score 1):

***Old faithful*** -- [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/old-faithful)

> (noun) You can refer to something that has been used or has existed for a long time as an old faithful, especially when it is something you can rely on.
>   *We tested a selection of vacuum cleaners, from old faithfuls to those with the latest features.*

***Tried and true*** -- [AHD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/tried+and+true)

> Tested and proved to be worthy or reliable
>   *Let me deal with it-my method is tried and true.*

Comment: Just a heads-up, people have been hit with down votes before for having the temerity to answer requests for a single word with multiple-word expressions...

Comment: *Old faithful* is an Americanism, and may not make sense to English speakers outside the US.

Comment: @oerkelens True, that. Thanks for the heads-up. My reasoning is, single words would simply be synonyms of ***reliable***. So, I provided something extra.